# jQuery convert ajax post id => nil to key => value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to drag a div into a specific drop zone. From this I would like to post to my server the ID of the dragged div.

My code looks like this

```
    function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: ui.draggable.attr('id'),
            dataType: 'script',
            url: '/users/sort'
            })
}
```

I am getting this from my post values

```
user_2 => nil
```

When I want this such that I can process it.

```
user => user_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: { user: ui.draggable.attr('id') }, // <= Look! This line changed.
        dataType: 'script',
        url: '/users/sort'
        })
}
```